# Let onDraw method of custom View not execute repeat

Tags: android, ondraw

I set a custom View, and as an Item of ListView to display.

When I slide ListView, onDraw of the custom View will execute repeat. Click Item will execute onDraw repeat too. In the custom View I just drew a picture, I don't need the repeated execution. how to let it only perform once?

Edit:  No rewrite any method except Rewrite the structure function and onDraw method.

No call any method except call canvas.drawBitmap in onDraw method.

Comment: Did you look at this ?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may call invalidate() method which forcebly calls onDraw().